# CSS calc exponential division

Tags: css, math, css-calc

I have a base value `16px`, I need to divide it by the ratio `1.067` 6 times to reach the desired outcome value `10.84px`, I'm currently doing this via:

```
body {
  font-size: calc(16px / 1.067 / 1.067 / 1.067 / 1.067 / 1.067 / 1.067);
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to write this calculation so I don't have to repeat the ratio multiple times? I was thinking something like this:

```
calc(16px / (1.067 * 6))
```

But that gives me an incorrect outcome value of `2.49px`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it's should be `pow(1.067,6)`  but not yet supported https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#exponent-funcs

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS variables to prepare the different divider:

```css
:root {
  --x1:1.067;
  --x2:calc(var(--x1)*var(--x1));
  --x3:calc(var(--x2)*var(--x1));
  --x4:calc(var(--x3)*var(--x1));
  --x5:calc(var(--x4)*var(--x1));
  --x6:calc(var(--x5)*var(--x1));
}

body {
  font-size: calc(16px / var(--x6));
}
```

```html
some text here
```

You can optimize if you don't want all of them:

```css
:root {
  --x1:1.067;
  --x2:calc(var(--x1)*var(--x1));
  --x3:calc(var(--x2)*var(--x1));
  --x6:calc(var(--x3)*var(--x3));
}

body {
  font-size: calc(16px / var(--x6));
}
```

```html
some text here
```